# How do I pass pageToken in a query to get the next set of views?

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, node-modules

I tried to get pageToken in response by adding maxResults as 2 in options with query,
When  I used that pageToken (that I got in response from my previous code) in options with maxResults then I didn't get the next set of results,
I got empty array in response, how should we pass pageToken with query and maxResults to get the next set of results?

**If I use pageToken in options->**

```
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery')
const projectId = 'bigqueryproject1-279307'
const keyFilename = './credentials/client_secrets.json'
async function query () {
  const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery({ projectId, keyFilename })
  // Queries the U.S. given names dataset for the state of Texas.

  const query = 'SELECT * FROM bigqueryproject1-279307.abcdef12k3.__TABLES__ WHERE type = 2'
  const options = {
    maxResults: 2,
    pageToken: 'BE6GBKCXOMAQAAASA4EAAEEAQCAAKGQEBABBAARAWCXBK==='
  }

  const job = await bigqueryClient.query(query, options)
  console.log('******job*****', job)
}
query()
```

**Result=>**

```
[ [],
  null,
  { kind: 'bigquery#getQueryResultsResponse',
    etag: 'taA51Ro5PrAMPypjzfMwCg==',
    schema: { fields: [Array] },
    jobReference:
     { projectId: 'bigqueryproject1-279307',
       jobId: 'a212f570-0d92-4208-92ac-71aa2da82364',
       location: 'US' },
    totalRows: '0',
    totalBytesProcessed: '0',
    jobComplete: true,
    cacheHit: false } ]
```

**I am getting empty array as response rather than getting next 2 view**

Answer (score 1):

I admit that `pageToken` parameter doesn't exist in generic query [*request*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#queryrequest) body of the `jobs.query` Bigquery API [method](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query), thus you can't also find it in the relevant `bigquery.query(query, options, callback)` *NodeJS* Bigquery client library [class](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQuery.html#query) method as well.

In order to get the desired effect for the user query results pagination, you can consider adjusting [job.getQueryResults()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/Job.html#getQueryResults) method in your code, fetching the certain rows from the query [Job](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQuery.html#createJob) as per defined `maxResults` and `pageToken` properties.